# Is it possible to make apache also work for jsp pages?

Tags: apache-2.2, jsp

I've used wampserver for serving PHP requests.

Now I want to use jsp,is it possible for apache?

Otherwise I have to install tomcat,is there a wampserver alike tool out there?

Answer (score 2):

Java Server Pages can not be interpreted by Apache httpd directly. You have to install a Servlet container like Apache Tomcat or Jetty which you can connect to Apache httpd via mod_ajp or mod_proxy.

Comment: Oh seems complicated to use apache to server jsp.Is there a wampserver alike tool for tomcat?

Comment: This here sounds interesting: http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/tomcat6.php It also allows to make calls between PHP and Java code. I haven't tried it yet, but I would, if I had to integrate PHP with Java.

Comment: I don't want to install database,java,tomcat manually,is there a tool to automate the setup ?